# Payhip - Stripe payment testing

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm new to both Payhip & Stripe. I'm testing out both products by setting up a test product in Payhip & making a purchase using a dummy visa card number (4242424242424242) from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards)

Payhip is connected to Stripe.

I keep getting the message - Your card was declined. Your request was in live mode, but used a known test card.

I've searched on google & read thorugh stripe documentation. I'm not able to find anything useful to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not linked to Stripe i any form. There no way out to use a test card with Payhip. I contacted Payhip support & was advised as follows

One can either use a 100% off coupon (see here: [Testing Checkout Flow](https://help.payhip.com/article/107-testing-checkout-flow)) or put through a live transaction and refund yourself afterwards ([How Do I Refund a Transaction?](https://help.payhip.com/article/147-how-do-i-refund-a-transaction))

Answer (score 0):

To use a test card in your integration, you need to use the test mode secret key instead. You can get it from the Stripe Dashboard -> Developer -> API Keys page.

Comment: Thank you @qichuan. Where should I put the test mode secret key in Payhip?